# HID Device Interface in macOS

Tags: c++, macos, driver, hid, iokit

I have to create a software/driver for OSX that interact with HID device connected through USB. The purposes of the application are as follows,

1. Detect when HID device is plugged in or Removed. The PID and VID of the device is known.
2. Read HID device serial number, firmware version and other details about the connected device that matches with the VID and PID
3. Get Reports and set reports to the HID device when it is connected.
4. Communicate with another application through which the user can alter the HID device setting

I am not a driver developer, but have experience in C, C++, Obj C etc. I am wondering what will be the best way to achieve the mentioned objectives. That is should I develop kernel extension (driver) or is there a better alternative?.

The challenges I face are,

- Starting with driver development
- Mac application communicating with the driver.

Either way, this is a new field for me. Can you please suggest some documents or sample codes, from with I can start.

Also kindly mention forums, or communities which might be helpful in developing device driver for mac.

Thankyou you all for the help. :)

Comment: Did you succeed working on this? I am facing the same situation for HyperX FPS Mechanical keyboard. The windows and FN keys don't work. I wan't to create my own System extension / driverKit to fix this and share it other users.

Answer (score 3):

MacOS X already has drivers for HID devices. So you don't need to develop a special driver/kernel extension for it.

You can use cross-platform opensource library [hidapi](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi) for communication with HID devices.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: Updated 12/2023 with information about DriverKit; original question and answer predate the introduction of DriverKit.)

The other answer (hidapi) to this question certainly holds true for a bunch of different use cases, and I advise going down that route where possible. Rather than using the hidapi wrapper, you can also use the [`IOHIDManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/iohidmanager_h) system API directly.

There are certainly cases where you'll need to dig into driver development proper, however. In particular, if the HID device needs to act as the system keyboard or pointing device, but isn't picked up as you want it to by the built-in HID stack, you might need to (or want to) develop a DriverKit (pre-10.15: kernel-space) driver. (You do have the option of injecting events into the windowing system from userspace too, though, so I'd prototype your use case with that first, if in doubt.)

You haven't quite given us enough detail about what you're trying to do, or the nature of the device to really say for sure what approach might be best.

For HIDDriverKit sample code, [Apple publishes some here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/driverkit_sample_code?language=objc). For kernel level, check out Apple's own Open Source code. (IOHIDFamily, IOUSBFamily, etc.) Searching the web for the classes you're working with will also turn up some third-party OSS code on Github etc.

Stack Overflow and the relevant Apple developer mailing lists (Darwin-drivers, Darwin-kernel, or Usb, depending on the question), and maybe the developer forums (I find them hard to follow/monitor consistently) are probably the best communities for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer for my query. I need to interface dedicated gaming devices which includes mouses, keyboards and gaming consoles. The settings in the devices (such as DPI, pointer speed, back-light color and brightness etc) will need to be changed. I need to detect when the device is connected or disconnected.

Also, the keys in the devices can have custom actions, which can be configured from the system, for example, on click of a button, it will need to simulate a keyboard keypress.

Comment: It will depend a lot on specifics, but you should be able to do a lot of these using the userspace HID API documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/intro/intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000970-CH202-SW1) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/iokit/1659967-iohidmanager.h). There's also [some potentially useful sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/navigation/index.html#section=Topics&topic=Drivers%2C%20Kernel%2C%20%26amp%3b%20Hardware&filter=HID+Sample+Code).

Comment: In practice, it will depend on how exactly your device is structured. You might need to do some things via the lower-level USB I/O Kit API (which again also exists in user space) in addition to the HID Manager API. I'm not sure about reprogramming buttons - for that you may need to drop to kernel level after all, depending on specifics. If you were a consulting client, I'd recommend setting aside a week or so of exploring/prototyping the features where we're not 100% sure on implementation details before deciding exactly how to structure the overall driver software.

Comment: (In other words, the scope here quickly exceeds the kind of thing that can be feasibly answered in a Stack Overflow question; I hope I've managed to point you in a useful direction at least.)

Comment: I should probably also link to the source for the OS X USB HID driver we maintain: https://github.com/pmj/QemuUSBTablet-OSX (This is an unusual kind of driver though, so I'm not sure how much help it will be.)

Comment: Much thanks for the understanding the case, and detailed explanation. I have cloned Qemu Project, it looks small and simple. I have build QemuUSBTablet target, but not able to load the kext created. 
'kextutil -n -t QemuUSBTablet.kext
QemuUSBTablet.kext has no Info.plist file.'
How do I compile and load kext? Other Targets complain 'Not valid for running the scheme'

Comment: I don't know why you're not ending up with an info.plist. Works OK for me. Check what the target settings say about the info.plist I guess? Note that the various targets are for various different versions of OS X, so you need different versions of the OS X SDK to build them - and those ship with different versions of Xcode, as indicated in the documentation. Make sure you're using the right version of Xcode to build. (We're veering far off the original question here - if you have issues with the code I linked, open a bug on github, if you have other questions, start a new SO one.)

Answer (score 0):

You have three options to develop your driver:

1. Build from scratch with c lib: https://github.com/libusb/hidapi
2. Follow HID Driver documentation from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/hiddriverkit, for example:

   - Communicate between Client and User: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/communicating_between_a_driverkit_extension_and_a_client_app
   - StylusHIDDriver: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/hiddriverkit/handling_stylus_input_from_a_human_interface_device
3. Reference to some of GitHub resource like:
   https://github.com/astarasikov/osxhidtouch

As I aware, it seems that number 2 is the best way to develop your driver. But number 3 also a great place to start your development. Overall, my suggestion is number 2 or number 3.